# Why does "last" fail on Alpine with "last couldn't open file '/dev/null/wtmp' "?

Tags: alpine, last

Why is the `last` command failing on my fresh install of Alpine 3.12?

```
$ last
couldn't open file '/dev/null/wtmp': Not a directory

wtmp begins Thu Jan  1 00:00
```

(on a Linode server if that matters)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a long known issue. Alpine uses libmusl instead of glibc. It seems that

> musl does not use or even support
> `/dev/null/utmp` or `/dev/null/wtmp` (and nothing appears to get written to
> `/var/log/wtmp`); so I guess there might not be a way to fix this.

https://gitlab.alpinelinux.org/alpine/aports/-/issues/3282#note_15597

There is an open [issue](https://gitlab.alpinelinux.org/alpine/aports/-/issues/3282) for it on the Alpine Linux page and apparently it is a [milestone](https://gitlab.alpinelinux.org/alpine/aports/-/milestones/155) for the 3.14.0 release of Alpine Linux. Until than there is probably no workaround for this.